# Directives in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

Hi I am trying to learn AngularJS Directives and I came really close but would like to extend my learning by cleaning and de-coupling my directive code.

***Directive:***

```
app.directive('ngSparkline', function () {
var url = "http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/forecast/daily?mode=json&units=imperial&cnt=14&callback=JSON_CALLBACK&q=";
return {
    restrict: 'A',
    require: '^ngCity',
    transclude: true,
    scope: {
        ngCity: '@'
    },
    templateUrl: 'app/partials/weatherTemplate.html',
    controller: ['$scope', '$http', function($scope, $http) {
  $scope.getTemp = function(city) {}
}],
    link: function (scope, iElement, iAttrs) {
        scope.getTemp(iAttrs.ngCity);
        scope.$watch('weather', function (newVal) {
            if (newVal) {
                var highs = [];

                angular.forEach(scope.weather, function (value) {
                    highs.push(value.temp.max);
                });

                chartGraph(iElement, highs, iAttrs);
            }
        });
    }
};
```

});

As you can see I am not trying to write inline template rather use templateUrl. Now the problem is for the controller when I try using a .js controller instead of writing the controller code inline, I receive an error. How do I achieve this.

***I tried:***

I tried passing

```
controller: '@', 
name: 'ctrl'
```

and I pass the 'ctrl' as:

```
<div ng-sparkline ng-city="San Francisco" ctrl="weatherController"></div>
```

it gives me controller not found. My project structure is something like below.

[image]

- What am I doing wrong?
- Is there a better/correct way of doing this?

Please suggest.

Note: I am learning this exercise from "http://www.ng-newsletter.com/posts/directives.html"

Comment: Is your controller referenced correctly in your app?  Like did you include it in your script refs or bundle?

Comment: you should actually pass the name of the controller directly to the `controller` property on the directive, in the same way you specified the path to the `templateUrl` property.  The directive should own and be in direct control of it's Controller. It is never appropriate or useful for the consumer to have to provide or manage the Controller for the directive themselves; the Controller should hold all the logic the directive uses, and should not be dependent on the consumer to provide this logic.

Comment: @Claies I tried passing the controller i.e. 'app/controllers/mycontroller.js' and throws an error invalid function.

Comment: the `controller` property doesn't take a path to a file, it takes the function DI injection as a parameter to find the function (i.e. `weatherController`).  Angular can register functions from anywhere on the disk, as long as the `<script>` is loaded on the HTML page, your directive doesn't care where it's stored.  It does care where the *templates* are stored, however, since those don't have a corresponding `<script>`.

Comment: so you mean to say to give it as 

['$weatherController', function ($weatherController) {

??            

};
}],

Can you correct me if I am wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Why not just specify `ng-controller` on your element? If `WeatherController` is defined somewhere else then it doesn’t affect your directive definition, just leave the controller out of there.

```
<div ng-sparkline ng-city="San Francisco" ng-controller="WeatherController"></div>
```

Provided somewhere you do have the controller defined like

```
app.controller('WeatherController', ['$scope', '$http', function ($scope, $http) {
    $scope.getTemp = // …
}]);
```

<sup>(BTW, if you noticed, the AngularJS convention is to name controllers in UpperCase fashion.)</sup>